# Optimize member array access (mov instruction)

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, assembly

Here's a part of the perf profiler report:

```
for (node* p = array[index]; p != NULL; p = p->next )
   52,55 :           cb40a:       mov    (%edi,%edx,4),%ebp
```

As you can see half of the time spent in that function is spent on the particular instruction that represents "p = array[index]" access (%edi is "this" pointer, %edx is calculated index).

1. Why does it take so long? There're calls and comparisons inside the loop, but most time is spent on this executed once simple mov. I suppose usually this list only contains few elements and thus loop body does not take much time, but still...
2. How to optimize it?

The array access happens only once, the function takes the start element from it. Usually, the function then will end up comparing node data to the key and returning "p" or NULL if comparison fails. I.e. most of the time p->next is NULL.

Even if we assume that memory access happens only twice: in array[index] and in p->next, then why the first one is so much slower than the second one (which is about 5% of function)?

If this is the cache issue I'd like to know why it can happen and how to find possible solutions (i.e rearrange memory access, etc).

The complete function (kind of):

```
node* list::find(int key)
{
  if (!this->array) return 0;
  node* dummy = 0;
  int index = calcindex(key);
  for (node* p = this->array[index]; p != NULL; p = p->next)
  {
    if (p->key() == key && check(p->data, key))
      return p;
    dummy = p; // forgot to remove this stuff, probably optimized away
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here key() and compare() are simple inlined functions.

Comment: may be try prefetching the array before? (something like, `__builtin_prefetch(array, 0, 3);` somewhere before it's used in the function?

Comment: Hm, will it help given that the function need to access array only once and only single element from it (the start node)?

Comment: Are you sure that the `mov` is resulting from indexing into `array`.  I would be surprised if gcc didn't initialize `p` to the appropriate element. The `mov` statement is probably from `p = p->next`.

Comment: That seems quite unlikely to me, could you post a compilable example of what you're really doing? Perhaps most of the array entries are `nullptr` already, i.e. empty lists?

Comment: No, p->next is done via lea 0xc(%ebp),%eax.

Comment: If the array access only happens once, then you really aren't spending *half of the time* on it unless the body of the `for` loop is a single `if` statement with an embedded return.  In that case, there is no need to optimize.

Comment: Yes, most of the time p->next is null, i.e. after p=array[index] we execute loop body and exit function.

Comment: If your last statement holds, then can it be anything else other than a cache issue?

Comment: Yes, maybe, but can you elaborate? Why it can be the cache issue and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I can't say why your array is not in the cache - it could anything, (say for example you've not accessed it in a while), and as a result, it has to be fetched into the cache as you are about to access it. Typically for such situations, you can try periodically accessing the array (even if you don't do anything with it) so that when you really do come to do something with it, it's there in the cache and you are not hit with the cost of having to pull it in. There's no guarantee that it would work (I'm not a real expert in this area to say whether it is possible at all to keep something in cache

Comment: Please, show bigger part of the profile, like the whole loop and several insns before it. The insn may stall due to the memory access, but it may stall waiting for its operands as well.

Comment: Sounds more like branch misprediction penalty is somehow attributed to this particular instruction.